# Live Video Streaming To Server in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am developing an application, which broadcast the video from mobile to server. I have searched Google and many questions on Stack overflow.

I found some useful links like [`spydroid-ipcamera`](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/). It is working fine. but if two users open the same link then video streaming is disconnecting.